# Activity bundle missing extras even though they should always be added in the newIntance method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, activity-lifecycle, android-bundle

I have an unexpected crash on my app in production. I have an activity that I always start using a ***newInstance*** method that add some extras to the intent :

```
public static Intent newInstance(final Context context, @NonNull final Location location) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationActivity.class);

        final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putParcelable(BUNDLE_ITEM_LOCATION, Location);
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        return intent;
    }
```

And here is my onCreate method :

```
@Override
@CallSuper
public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null || !extras.containsKey(BUNDLE_ITEM_LOCATION)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(LocationActivity.class.getName()
                + " must be created by using newInstance()");
    }

                 [... Some other code ...]
}
```

And this IllegalArgumentException is thrown in production. It's super weird because this case should never happen. Any idea about the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is Location is your Model or the android.location?

Comment: @ParthivMistri this is my model

Comment: @MohamedAshik the new instance method and the onCreate are in the same class so sure this is the same final String.

Comment: yes. can you share how you calling this newInstance method to open the activity?

Comment: @MohamedAshik simply something like  this.startActivity(LocationActivity.newInstance(location));

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static Intent newInstance(final Context context, @NonNull final Location location {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(BUNDLE_ITEM_LOCATION, Location);
        return intent;
    }
```

Comment: So it could come from the bundle? I will try this thanks!

Comment: @DenisPinna Let me know if you are still facing the same thing.

Comment: @Patrhiv Mistri apparently the problem is still here with this change..